# Tab autocomplete works initially but freezes after computer goes to sleep

Tags: command-line, ssh, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I am using Ubuntu terminal through Windows Subsystem for Linux on a new Lenovo laptop with Windows 11. Tab works to autocomplete paths when I initially start the terminal, but if my computer has gone to sleep, tab freezes the terminal. Ctrl+c does not work to unfreeze it, and I am still able to access files/directories if I type the path out fully. Autocomplete also still works if I ssh into a remote server and then log back out, and I have had no issues while connected to remote hosts. The only way that I have found to fix the issue is to restart the computer - opening a new terminal results in the same issue.
I do not have a background in programming or computer science, so please let me know if I can clarify anything.